# How execute expl3 commands inside lua code

Tags: luatex, expl3

When I try execute `expl3` commands inside Lua code, I get an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\\  ->\let \reserved@e
                       \relax \let \reserved@f \relax \@ifstar {\let \reserv...

l.13 \test{1}
```

Yes, I know, what the example below possible write using fully `expl3` functions, but I have some code, which save some data in Lua, so I need in example, how to execute `expl3` code in Lua. Help me please that my example work in Lua. The second question, how I can in `\directlua` use space instead of `~`, because `~` used in Lua too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn \g__my_prop
  { value0 = -1 , value1 = 0 }
\cs_new_eq:NN \PropRemovecn \prop_remove:cn
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \directlua{%
    if #1==1 then
      tex.print("\\PropRemovecn{g__my_prop}{value1}")
    end
  }}
\begin{document}
\test{1}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your error comes from `\directlua` trying to expand `\\`. You get the same error from `\edef\x{\\}` (in LaTeX versions older than 2020-02-02). You need to make sure that `\\` becomes two character tokens before the Lua interpreter kicks in. You can use either `\string\\prop...` or `\luaescapestring{\prop...}` (or, more `expl3`-y, `\lua_escape:e`).

Also, different from expanding a macro, whose replacement text is already tokenized, when you do `tex.print` it is as if you typed those tokens in the input file, at the time `\directlua` is expanded. Since you use your `\test` command outside of an `expl3` code context, `_` and `:` are not letters, so `\prop_remove:cn` is misinterpreted as `\prop _remove:cn`. As if you were typing the code yourself, you have to use `\ExplSyntaxOn/Off`:

```
tex.print("\luaescapestring{\\ExplSyntaxOn\\prop_remove:cn{g__my_prop}{value1}\\ExplSyntaxOff}")
```

However this has some overhead, and if you happened to use `\test` in the middle of some `expl3` code, then it would recklessly do `\ExplSyntaxOff` without you wanting it to. I recommend defining an interface for `\prop_remove:cn`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn \g__my_prop
  { value0 = -1 , value1 = 0 }
\cs_new_eq:NN \PropRemovecn \prop_remove:cn
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \directlua{%
    if #1==1 then
      tex.print("\luaescapestring{\PropRemovecn{g__my_prop}{value1}}")
    end
  }}
\begin{document}
\test{1}
\end{document}
```

You can also pass a catcode table to `tex.print` as Ulrike suggested, then LuaTeX will print the tokens with that catcode setting. If you load `l3cctab` then you can use `\int_use:N \c_code_cctab` (the code definition has to be inside `\ExplSyntaxOn/Off`, in this case):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{l3cctab}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn \g__my_prop
  { value0 = -1 , value1 = 0 }
\cs_new_eq:NN \PropRemovecn \prop_remove:cn
\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \lua_now:e {%
    if~#1==1~then~
      tex.print(\int_use:N \c_code_cctab,
        "\lua_escape:e {\prop_remove:cn{g__my_prop}{value1}}")
    end
  }}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\test{1}
\end{document}
```

As for your second question: if you need lots of spaces, define the command outside of the `expl3` code environment (the fact that it's in `\directlua` doesn't matter, as the tokenization rules still apply when you define the `\test` macro).

Comment: `tex.print(\int_use:N\c_code_cctab,"\\prop_remove:cn{g__my_prop}{value1}")` should work to set the catcode table (needs l3cctab).

Comment: @phelype-oleinik I edited my question and your variant compile with the same error.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy See my edit

Comment: +1: Are you sure, that `LaTeX versions older than **2020-02-02**` is correct? :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Yes (as odd as it may seem :-). In the current development version of LaTeX ``\\`` has been made `\protected`, so it doesn't expand in `\edef`/`\write`/`\directlua`/etc. This development version is scheduled to be released on 2020-02-02, so it's LaTeX-from-the-future :-) You can try this version now using `lualatex-dev` (or `xelatex-dev` or `pdflatex-dev`).